# JS call multiple stored functions, start with this

Tags: javascript

I can store a function in a variable and call it later like this

```
var storedFunction = functionName;

//Later On
storedFunction(); //Equivalent to functionName()
```

How can I store a function like this and call it later, also executing `this` when its called so `this` would be the

```
var storedFunction = this.function1().function2();
```

Later I could call it like this and `this` would be the class.

```
class MyClass {
    method() {
        storedFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: `var storedFunction = function1.bind(this);` will lock the `this` context of where this line is. You can then call `storedFunction()` from anywhere, while keeping the original context

Comment: Any way I can execute `function2` also?

Comment: if `function1` returns an Object (or instance of a class) with a `"function2"` property, yes you can. **Edit**: maybe you meant to store the whole thing? `var storedFunction = (function() { return this.function1().function2(); }).bind(this);`

Comment: Ok, when I tried it, `bind(this)`, this acted like normal and used the object while it was being defined. How can I delay to when it is called?

Comment: Ok, I did not understand that from your original question. Then, you could do `var storedFunction = function() { return this.function1().function2(); };` (without the bind). And then, in your class, call it like so: `storedFunction.call(this, /* parameters */);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function like this :

```
function myFunction(){
    return {
        function inner(){
            return 'some data'
        }
    }
}
```

When you call `myFunction` with `myFunction()` returned value is an object like this:

```
{
    inner: function (){ return 'some data'; }  
}
```

If you want to store `inner` function just need store your value with it's key from returned object, like this:

```
let myInnerFunction = myFunction().inner;

...

//and when you want call that
myInnerFunction ()
```

In your case this is correct:

```
let storedFunction = this.function1().function2;
```

If you want to run `function1` and `function2` when you call there is a simple way:

```
let storedFunction = () => {
    return this.function1().function2();
}

// or without arrow function

let storedFunction = function () {
    return this.function1().function2();
}.bind(this)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If I understand your code correctly, your last bit will still execute `this.function1()` on definition, and then execute `function2()` on call. I need to call both `function1()` and `function2()` as well as `this`, if possible

Answer (score 1):

The dot operator (`.`) is the *object access operator*. That means whenever you see it (not related to a number), the code is attempting to access a property or method (function) of that object.

That means: `this.something` is attempting to access the `something` property on an object referred to as `this`.

Related, then `function1().function2()` means `function2()` must be a method of an object too. But, in this case, the object *must* be returned from `function1()` in order for this to work.

So here is some sample code that would do what you expect.

```js
function function1() {
  return {
    function2: () => {
      console.log('called function2 from function1 on "this"');
    }
  }
}
function1.bind(this);
this.function1().function2();

// Using class syntax

class OtherClass {
  function2() {
    console.log('Used class keyword');
  }
}

class MyClass {

  constructor() {
    this.veryOddThingToDo = this.function1().function2;
  }

  function1() {
    return new OtherClass();
  }
}

const myClass = new MyClass();
// Get reference to function2() from "MyClass.function1()" call
const oddness = myClass.veryOddThingToDo;

// This is exactly: this.function1().function2() referenced"
oddness();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I store your last line so that I can call within an instance of `class` that `function1()` belongs to (which then returns a 2nd instance of a class to which `function2()` belongs)?

Comment: @Jack  Please see the updated answer with both solutions.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to store `this.function1().function2();` in a variable and then call it late with something like `storedFunction()`?

Comment: @Jack  Yes - see updated answer - but I have no idea why you would want to do this!

Comment: I definitely will. Thanks for your time. But as you said, I have a very weird problem. I apologize for my communication errors. Alfefseen was able to answer my question the, however.

Comment: @Jack - glad you got it sorted out.